# Alternative to ccache for non-compiler commands

Tags: shell-scripting, caching

I am using `ccache` to cache output files. But one of my other tools in my build pipeline is not a compiler, and gets an input and an output. And I was wondering, if there are alternative tools, which works like `ccache`. E.g. my tool is a Python script:

```
$ python3 foo.py input.txt -a -b
Generated output.txt
```

And I am looking for a tool, that works like `ccache`, but can cache the output, depending on its parameter. E.g:

```
$ cache-tool --hash=input.txt --output=output.txt python3 foo.py input.txt -a -b
Generated output.txt
```